# Why does mysqli_affected_rows takes link as parameter instead of query?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any reason for `mysqli_affected_rows` takes `$link` as first parameter instead of query?

**example usage for mysqli_num_rows**

```
$con = mysqli_connect(..);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='5'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($query);
//output: 1
```

**example usage for mysqli_affected_rows**

```
$con = mysqli_connect(..);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE id='5'");
echo mysqli_affected_rows($con);
//output: 1
```

Shouldn't it be better that `mysqli_affected_rows` takes $query instead?

Comment: *"Shouldn't it be better that mysqli_affected_rows takes $query instead?"* - Why would you think that that would be better? Did you not consult both manuals on this?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner at least, you can do it in one line if it used $query instead. I understood why it doesn't, thanks to answer below. And yeah I did  read manuals but there was no information about my question, or I couldn't "see" it.

Comment: It's shown in this area https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-class.mysqli.html and shows a very basic statement: *"Represents a **connection** between PHP and a MySQL database."* - I feel that the same statement in both links are self-explanatory and very very simple, IMHO. You just needed to dig a bit deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `mysqli_num_rows` counts the number of the results in the **query**.

But `mysqli_affected_rows` queries the **server** to get information of the last event.